# How do social media platforms stay up-to-date with messages and posts?

Tags: multithreading, messaging, social-networks

This is a question I have always wondered

Is it as simple as repetitive pinging of a server in a seperate thread or is it more complicated than that?

I am only talking about the app version not the browser as it is obvious that browsers have direct access to a servers database

Comment: The browser most definitely does _not_ have direct access to the server's database; that would be pretty awful software engineering for all sorts of reasons (separation of concerns, security, scalability, and many others).

Comment: More generally, you want to know how a *mobile phone app* can *receive notifications* when *stuff happens on the server*? When the app is running, or also when it isn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called [Polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)).
It is possible to design your app to work that way, but it is often inefficent.
Another approach would be to let the server inform the client when it has new information. These are called [Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)).
They are usually more efficent because the client just needs to wait for updates and the server isn't bombarded with requests.
You are right that this often happens in another thread since the reading operation blocks (it waits for more data to read).

Comment: Generally a hybrid of pull and push mode are used

Comment: Polling isn't inherently inefficient, in some cases it can actually be more efficient than events/interrupts. It depends on the volume of messages and how sensitive to latency the use case is. Events/interrupts are more efficient when the message frequency is lower than the latency threshold (which I would expect is the case for the vast majority of situations). Polling is more efficient when the message frequency is higher than the latency threshold, i.e. if there's always 1 or more messages waiting when you check.